# How to configure cwl to provide verbatim highlighting for custom code?

Tags: listings, texstudio, verbatim, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to customize `cwl` file to provide verbatim highlighting. I am trying to get assistance from [TeXstudio : User manual](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/master/utilities/manual/usermanual_en.html#description-of-the-cwl-format), and my `cwl` file contains the following

```
\basoom{verbatimSymbol}
```

This is what I get

[image]

TeXstudio thus, does not actually highlight the argument itself as verbatim, but rather highlights the input after the closing bracket. It is possible to solve this by using `|` for brackets, but arguments defined using LaTeX only appear in curly brackets. Thus, the possible solutions are

1. Modify the `cwl` to highlight only the argument between curly brackets as verbatim
2. Define the command itself as to accept `|` for brackets for its argument

This is my MWE

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}, t, handout]{beamer}

\usetheme{Dresden}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{ppl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\encodingdefault}{T1}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{LaTeX}{
    % style
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    basicstyle=\linespread{0.8}\ttfamily\color{DodgerBlue3},
}

\lstset{style=LaTeX}

\newcommand{\basoom}[1]{\lstinline|#1|} % for testing

\begin{document}
    
    \basoom{BasmahWantsMeHappy}BasmahWantsMeHappy
    
    \basoom|BasmahWantsMeHappy|
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this different from your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/623238/208544)?

Comment: You could make the cwl entry `\basoom{arg%definition}` then follow the steps [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541363/texstudio-add-custom-syntax-highlighting/570642#570642) to define custom highlighting for the arg. Replace `\footnote` with `\basoom` in that example